# Node JS escape angle brackets from description text

Tags: node.js, express, pug, angle, brackets

I have a problem with my description text which I read in pug HTML template with Express.js and Node.js.

Inside MongoDB, my description does not contain angle bracket on first and last character places, but when I show description text on web page every description text starts and ends with `< >`
Sample: printing value from db `#{item.description}` the result on web page  `< some description text >`

Why are these brackets shows and how to remove it?

Comment: I think your `description` in mongodb might be having `&lt;` at the beginning and `&gt;` at the end. Can you confirm?

Comment: Here is description in mongodb:     "description" : " Redux is a simple library that helps you manage the state of your JavaScript app. Despite that simplicity, it's easy to fall down rabbit holes when learning it. I often find myself explaining Redux, and almost always start by showing how I'd implement it. So that's what we'll do here: Start from scratch and build a working Redux implementation. Our implementation won't cover every nuance, but we'll remove most of the mystery. ",

Comment: As you can see it has only " at the beginning and at the end. But, on website it's showing as < Redux is a simple library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for removing angle brackets from start and end of my description text.

This code results < description > in my pug view file.

```
   .description-short
    #{item.description}
```

When I changed to one row line:

```
.description-short #{item.description}
```

Angle brackets disappeared.

Comment: You're right. That makes sense. Because Pug/Jade assumes first word of each line as an html tag unless otherwise specified.